# How to automatically join conversation in Microsoft web chat (bot framework)

Tags: javascript, botframework, web-chat

I'm using https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md

I want the bot to receive a "join" message whenever the web-chat widget is displayed on the site.

The idea is that the human does not have to initiate the conversation.  The bot can respond to somebody joining the conversation with a welcome message.

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Webchat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "Welcome feature" has been a long term discussion and topic since Webchat v3. It looks like it has been fixed 2 days ago with this pull request: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/1286

There is now a sample on how to do that, located here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event/index.html

In a few words, the demo is the following:

```
  (async function () {
    // In this demo, we are using Direct Line token from MockBot.
    // To talk to your bot, you should use the token exchanged using your Direct Line secret.
    // You should never put the Direct Line secret in the browser or client app.
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication
    const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
    const { token } = await res.json();

    // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
        dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'webchat/join',
            value: { language: window.navigator.language }
          }
        });
      }
      return next(action);
    });

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
      store
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
  })().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Please note that due to the fact that this PR is quite new, it's not embedded in the `latest` release so you have to point to the `master` version of `webchat.js` file, not `latest`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>
```

And it's working: your bot side is notified of an activity of type `Event`, where you will be able to reply to your user, before he typed anything:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks!  Worked first time I loaded the page :)  I had to change the method of getting the token to use this from the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-a-direct-line-secret